# Change the way JSON.NET serializes property names

Tags: json, serialization, properties, json.net

How can I change the way Newtonsoft JSON.NET serializes property names of objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of ways:

1. You can manually control how it serializes using the `JsonTextWriter` class:

   - http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ReadingWritingJSON.htm
2. You could implement a custom `JsonConverter` that does what you want:

   - http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm
   - Example: [JSON.NET customizing the serialization to exclude a property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127749/json-net-customizing-the-serialization-to-exclude-a-property-name)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a model with the property names. And change them by creating some private variables that will be use to as return values for the properties. This is will direct the deserializer to reset the name of the property.

```
    private int _privateId;

    public int NameThatExistAlreadyInTheJson 
    {

        set { _privateId = value; }

    }
    public int NameYouWantItToBeDisplayInstead 
    {
        get { return _privateId; }
    }
```

Comment: Good one though it is not was I needed. I can use it when migrating JSON to a new "schema" :). Thanks.